# Does catch(...) actually catch all exceptions?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, stl

I see catch (...) does not catch all the exceptions and an annoying pop is thrown on end user.

```
size_t pos;
char *ptrDir="c:\\test";
std::string strDir = 
strDir.erase(strlen(ptrDir) - 1);
pos = strDir.find("Test");
try
{
    std::string strPat = strDir.substr(pos);
}
catch(...)
{
    std::cout<<"I am hiding Exception";
}
```

I am using Visual Studio 2005, Windows XP.

Note: Code is intentional to generate exceptions. It's a test code

Comment: You must be talking about exceptions like access violations, which aren't standard C++ exceptions - they're part of Structured Exception Handling: http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/general-programming/the-visual-c-exception-model-r2488

Comment: Maybe this is related to [SEH exceptions](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/seexception.aspx)? Probably you need to catch them, too.

Comment: Note: Structured Exceptions are not C++ exceptions (and thus not part of the language). They are part of the OS rather than the language though DevStudio provides an additional extension to the language to capture and manipulate them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code will likely generate access violations, which in VC++ are not going to be standard exceptions, they are in the realm of Structured Exceptions, which you can also catch but will need to use a different mechanism:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680657(v=vs.85).aspx
- [Structured Exception Handling](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/general-programming/the-visual-c-exception-model-r2488)